# webpack css-loader ignores & svg definition urls

Tags: svg, less, webpack

I'm using WebPack in a project with the css-loader.

An SVG element in this project has marker definitions and these markers are assigned in the stylesheet as follows:

Marker definition:

```
<defs>
    <marker id="line-marker">
        <circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5"></circle>
    </marker>
</defs>
```

Marker use:

```
path.nv-line {
  marker-mid: url('#line-marker');
}
```

I'm using the markers in the styles because I don't want to mess with the charting library I'm using but the css loader breaks on the URL.

Is there a way of ignoring some URL values in these rules or another way to prevent the loader from failing?

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be a less.js issue.

If the reference is made in a file that is not at the top-level of the less entry-point for processing, the url will be prepended.

I reported the issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2320

As a workaround, you can have these rules in less files at the top-level folder and the uri will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you compile with `--relative-url` option? If so the result is expected since this option specifically dictates to change any `url` to be relative to the file the `url` used in (and in this particular case Less cannot know this `marker-mid` url has nothing to do with the generated CSS file at all).

So as a workaround you need to choose one of those:

- turn `--relative-url` off
- hide the `url` from Less (i.e.: `marker-mid: ~"url(#line-marker)";`)
- remove `url` from there at all (i.e.: `marker-mid: '#line-marker';` - though I'm not sure if this way it will keep to conform to the standard)

Comment: Hi @seven-phases-max, the relative route was disabled but I'll give hiding the URL from LESS a go. Thanks for your advice!